# UDF Calculations Stop when i scroll or move Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook that has around 500 cells each calling 1 of 3 functions that send data to a web API then outputs it to the cell.

When i use my workbook in automatic calculations, they run when i press F9 But If i move the workbook/scroll down is stops all calculations without warning. Some of the cells may have finished.

**Is there a way of locking the screen or a way of keeping the functions running in the background while i move around excel?**

It also stops when i click onto another workbook.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Even in automatic calculations, it will stop the calculation util i leave it idle then it starts them up again without prompt.

Comment: Always best to show your code.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the code.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using please? I have a feeling the issue is therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User interaction with Excel whilst its calculating is supposed to interrupt calculation and restart it later (but the restart can be a bit problematic in my experience). You could try setting 
`Application.CalculationInterruptKey=xlNoKey` 
but it probably won't work from within a VBA UDF.
Really you need to rewrite the UDFs as asynchronous, but you can't do this with VBA - you need to be using the XLL interface either from C++ or .NET using XLDNA or Addin Express.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation stops when you grab the scrollbar because Excel does most of its processing on a single thread. That thread can't be scrolling the GUI and calculating formula results at the same time. Charles Williams is right on asynchronous UDFs. Support for asynchronous UDFs were introduced in the XLL SDK in Excel 2010. There's more detail on async UDFs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff475859.aspx